# I am unable to connect to an HP Procurve Switch with a patch cable

Tags: networking, putty, serial-port

I'm trying to connect to an HP Procurve switch 2610-48 PWR using Putty, an HP elite Probook laptop and a patch cable. When I connect to the console port using the appropriate cable, the command window open is blank, totally black with no blinking cursor and nothing saying 'Switch' or anything is on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the opposite type of cable? straight vs crossover?

Comment: That's the only cable I got. HP told me it would work.

Comment: How are you running `putty`? Do you actually have a serial port?

Comment: I launch putty and it opens up the command console in accordance with how putty normally launches. Yes, the HP laptop has a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

when you use putty to connect to an hp switch you must set the speed : 38400